# minipage flow into next line if too big

Tags: positioning, minipage

I'm trying to create minipages (or any kind of a box) that have a width of either `0.5\textwidth` or `\textwidth` depending on the size of its contents. I want the smaller minipages (with `0.5\textwidth`) to be next to eachother, the longer ones should break in the next line automatically.

What i'm trying to do is broken down in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \section*{Section}
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        Minipage with small contents
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill{}
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        Minipage with small contents
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill{}
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        Minipage with small contents
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill{}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        Minipage with a lot of very very long content which should overflow in the next line because it is not able to fit into the previous line.
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill{}
\end{document}
```

The result is the following where the last longer minipage should be in the next line beneath the 3rd minipage leaving an empty space where the long minipage is now:
[image]

(I'm generating the `.tex`-file with some program code so the order is not important, it doesn't matter if the minipages are sorted down and then left or down, left, down, left, ... because I can easily change the code.)

If possible I also wanted the minipage before the longer minipage to increase its size to `\textwidth` too but this is not the main part of this question.

I'm fairly new to LaTex, if there are any pre defined environments or anything that would be a better choice than minipages please feel free to let me know.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key changes to the OP's MWE:

1. use `%` between `minipage`s to avoid stray spaces.
2. Use `\hfill\allowbreak`to allow line breaks.
3. No need to shrink `minipage` to `.49\textwidth`.
4. align `minipage`s with `[b]` alignment.
5. apply a `\strut` before the end of each `minipage` to achieve proper line spacing.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \section*{Section}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        Minipage with small contents
    \strut\end{minipage}%
    \hfill\allowbreak%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        Minipage with small contents
    \strut\end{minipage}%
    \hfill\allowbreak%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        Minipage with small contents
    \strut\end{minipage}%
    \hfill\allowbreak%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
        Minipage with a lot of very very long content which should overflow in the next line because it is not able to fit into the previous line.
    \strut\end{minipage}%
    \hfill\allowbreak%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        Minipage with small contents
    \strut\end{minipage}%
    \hfill\allowbreak%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        Minipage with small contents
    \strut\end{minipage}%
    \hfill\allowbreak%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        Minipage with small contents
    \strut\end{minipage}%
    \hfill\allowbreak%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
        Minipage with a lot of very very long content which should overflow in the next line because it is not able to fit into the previous line.
    \strut\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. It's not very important but in my original code changing the width of the `minipage` to `0.5\textwidth` will push all the `minipages`s to a separate line. I just re-did the `0.49` again, I was just wondering what could cause this.

Comment: @miile7 If you are missing any line-ending `%` characters between the end of one `minipage` and the beginning of the next, an unwanted space character will be added.